# Add my dates from a custom post type to my ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I used this code to get the dates from a custom post type. How do i use this in my ajax call

```
<select id="date">
<?php
$dates = array();
$argez = (array( 'post_type' => 'latest_message'));
query_posts( $argez );
  if (have_posts())  : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $dates[] = get_the_date();
    $dates = array_unique($dates);
    print_r($datesun);

   endwhile; 
   foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo '<option value="' . $date . '">' . $date .'</option> ';
  }
 endif;
?>
</select>
```

I know i have to use something like this but not sure how. I need to be able to click on a date and all the posts from that date will be displayed

```
if ($_POST["topic"]!=0 ) {
$topic = array($_POST["topic"]);
} else {
     $topic = get_terms( 'topic', array('fields' => 'ids') );
     //$topic = array(implode(', ',$topic));

}


$myquery['tax_query'] = array(

        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topic',
            'terms' => $topic,
            'field' => 'id',
        )
    );
```

Comment: what do you want to call through ajax?

Comment: just tell me in plain words what exactly you want to do with your dropdown?

Comment: I have three other dropdowns which are already working (speaker/topic/). I need to get this one to work with them. So basically i need to click on a date and all the posts from that custom post type will be displayed

Comment: I have three other dropdowns which are already working (speaker/topic/). I need to get this one to work with them. So basically i need to click on a date and all the posts from that custom post type will be displayed @Ali

Comment: Can anyone help me with posting the dates in php